# How do I replace road brakes?

Tags: brakes, mechanical

How do I remove my old (Shimano Sora) brake callipers (dual pivot) and replace them with new (Shimano 105 5800) callipers?

([This is the bike if you want to know more components details](http://www.evanscycles.com/products/specialized/allez-sport-triple-2010-road-bike-ec019408)).

Comment: Posting a few similar questions like this today. I'm planning a major overhaul and thought it more appropriate, and useful to other users, to break up the question "How do I completely overhaul all of my components?" in to many smaller questions.

Comment: I'm sorry to downvote, but if you type your question into a popular search engine verbatim, the first hit is an instructional video. If you have started but encountered a problem, please describe the steps you've taken and the issues you now encounter.

Comment: @headeronly you are of course entitled to do so, but I don't see why you would - there is nothing about it in the help pages and questions like this are why we have the "reference" tag. 

The reason I posted this specific question is because I am about to embark on a complete overhaul thus I've been thinking about all the specific jobs involved. I was surprised to not find anything regarding this and other related tasks on here, I can (and have) answered my own question in this case.

Comment: @GriffinEvo: It's just that I didn't think the question showed any research effort. [Here's Sheldon's advice](http://sheldonbrown.com/calipers.html) on caliper installation. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zg36uCGg5Lk) found by G00gling your question. [This post](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21858/how-do-i-setup-these-brakes) explains in great detail how to install and adjust caliper brakes. The only remaining thing to address is how to remove your old calipers - on your bike there are recessed allen nuts holding them in place - get in there with an allen key!

Comment: I'm trying to work out the timeline here. Did you pose this question then immediately answer it yourself? Just wondering why... I can understand answering your own questions if you ask the question, do some research, then post your own answer. But that implies some kind of time difference between question and answer, and I don't see one here.

Comment: Although the question is easy enough to answer with a quick 'G' search, in retrospect there isn't a wealth of information on the subject on SE. Removed my downvote because by asking, then answering, the question, the OP has contributed useful info. But the timing of it all does smell like a rep grab ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCN do some great how to videos and will possibly be a good resource for you in your general overhaul of the bike. Here is one specific to you need for this post

Answer (score 2):

General guide to calliper swap:

1. Remove the cable ends (metal cap over the end of the cable) and loosen the cable clamp bolt (bolt holding the cable tight to the calliper).
2. Unfasten the calliper by loosening the calliper bolt (the one attaching the calliper to the frame). Take the calliper off the bike.
3. Attach the new calliper by the calliper bolt, making sure the calliper is straight (and on the correct end of the bike) and tighten so the calliper does not move around on the frame.
4. Align the pads to the wheel rim surface: Loosen the brake pad bolts, pull the calliper closed by hand, align the pads and tighten the pad bolts whilst keeping the calliper held closed.
5. Attach the cable to the calliper: put the cable in to position, pull the calliper closed on the rim and release it by a couple of millimeters, while holding the calliper in that position tighten the cable clamp bolt. Cap the new cable.
6. Adjust the alignment of the calliper position so brake pads are equidistant from the rim, double check the bolts are all properly tightened, pads are properly positioned (on the right side, straight, not touching the tire etc.), and test the brakes well before you *need* to use them.

Most importantly, carefully read the instructions included with the new callipers before fitting, don't just follow the guide above.

Comment: In other words, remove the old and install the new.  Assuming that both units use the same size brake post, there's nothing in the swap that isn't normal maintenance operations, other than the actual physical swap.